# CSS3 Overhead border-top transition looking like border-bottom

Tags: css

Trying to get a CSS3 transition to grow a `border-top` line above my links.  For some reason it just keeps growing as if its `border-bottom`.   Here is the code below, using SASS mixing.  Its currently working but growing from the bottom and not the top.

```
#linkReport {
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $defaultText;
    padding: 3px;

    &:after {
        @include outsideLinks;
    }

    &:hover:after {
      @include outsideHover;
    }
}

 @mixin outsideLinks() {
    border-top: 2px solid grey;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

@mixin outsideHover() {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Below is a demo created with the compiled CSS produced by the above code.

```css
#linkReport {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#linkReport:after {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#linkReport:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a id='linkReport' href='#'>Some Text</a>
```

Comment: Just a side note. If the problem is not with Sass (and you're sure it is not) then it is better to include the compiled CSS in the question instead of Sass code because that way people who know CSS well but not Sass could also help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is the top border appearing at the bottom?**

The pseudo-element was set to `display: block` and so by default it will be displayed in the next line below the main element's content. This is the reason why the `border-top` of the pseudo-element was looking as though it was `border-bottom`.

**Demo with problem:** (Added a height and background color so that you can see what I mean)

```css
#linkReport {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#linkReport:after {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: cyan;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#linkReport:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a id="linkReport">Some text</a>
```

---

**What is the solution?**

Instead of setting `display: block`, position the pseudo-element absolutely with respect to the parent element like in the below snippet.

```css
#linkReport {
  position: relative; /* add this */
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#linkReport:after {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  content: '';
  /* display: block; remove this */
  position: absolute; /* add this */
  top: 0px; /* add this */
  left: 0px; /* add this */
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#linkReport:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a id="linkReport">Some text</a>
```

Comment: Added the relative and absolute positioning and removed the display: block but it still only slides in from the bottom.

Comment: @user3622460: Did you remove the `display: block` like in my snippet and add the `top: 0px;` and `left: 0px`? If the problem exists after all these, please post the demo in question and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Ok adding the top and left at 0px worked, but it spaced all my links to the center of the div.

Comment: @user3622460: Can you show me your actual code? It can be fixed but not without seeing your code (the HTML I mean).

Comment: I fixed it, my mixin was included in another parent div so it changed the positioning of that div causing my inner links to shift.  Thanks for the help! =)